# Why does this while loop make the browser crash?

Tags: javascript, c++

I'm trying to compare the differences between similar snippets with javascript and C++. Here's my snippet:

```
var i = 0;

while (i<=10)
{
    document.write('Hello<br />');
    //i++;
}
```

With C++, if I write an equivalent snippet, I recall the console prints that line forever until I enter Ctrl + C. However, with Javascript, if I try to open the browser, it would crash. Does it have to do with the browser trying to load that "Hello" line forever until I force quit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't stop the process in javascript like you can do in C++.

In javascript most browsers even have a limit of the number of loop execution and most browsers (if not all) will crash with those type of loops.

Just no infinite looping in JS

Answer (score 0):

The browser probably wouldn't crash, but it would detect that your script had gone awry and ask you if you wanted to terminate the script. If you answer no, then it would loop forever and render the browser unusable.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will loop forever, you can stop it the infinite iterations thought just by stopping the js usage in the browser. For example in firefox choose (deactivate javascript)

There's the only way how to stop java script in browser but I'm sure there is many ways to do it.